# Passing GET Variable from one Bash/PHP Script to another

Tags: php, linux, bash, get

I am not sure the proper name for it, but I am executing PHP code within a Bash script on my Linux server. I have two of these Bash files and want to be able to pass a GET variable from one file to the next.

Here is a simplified version of the 1st file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

require("bash2.sh?id=1");
```

Here is a simplified version of the 2nd file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

echo $_GET['id'];
```

Currently, when I execute the 1st file on a Crontab, I get an error that says :

> PHP Warning:  require(bash2.sh?id=1): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /home/bash/bash1.sh on line 2

If I remove the `?id=1` from the `require()`, it executes without an error.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work... require searches for a exact name of the script, you can't pass variables to it since it's not a URL, it's a path. The only ways I know to pass variables between scripts are session_start() and header() but I'm afraid these won't work without a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You r thinking web...
What u put in the `require` is the actual file name the PHP engine will look for
using the OS.  i.e. it looks for a file called `bash2.sh?id=1` which u obviously do not have.

Either u call another script from withing, say with `system('./bash2.sh 2');`
Or, include, and use the method below to pass data.

file1

```
<?php
$id = 1;
require("bash2.sh");
```

file2

```
<?php
echo $id;
```

If u use the first example ( `system('./bash2.sh 2');`) Then in bash2.sh you will access the variable in the following way:

```
<?php
echo $argv[1]; //argv[0] is the script name
```

Comment: Should be `$argv[1]` not `argv[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a parameter to a static file on your harddrive. But you can define a global variable which is accessable by the reqired script.

```
<?php
$id=1
require("bash2.php");
```

and for your bash2.php:

```
<?php
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

No dude you should use arguments. When you execute php script (I am guessing in cron job), you add arguments like `some.php variable1 variable2` ..... etc`,

and then in php you get that varibale with `$argv[0], $argv[1] .... etc`.

That is the way from bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    exec("./bash2.sh $id");

?>
```

And then in the bash script you'll be able to access the first parameter passed as $1.

[More info here](http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Pass-Arguments-To-A-Bash-Script.htm) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Hope this helps!